# Create/Edit a Word Document from Visual Studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, ms-word

I have a word document with bookmarks in where text needs to be programatically inserted. 
i used to (in vba) open a copy of this document, insert the text, print it, and close it.

Now Ive moved to VS2010 I cant get the code right.

I have imported the Microsoft.Office.Interop namespace but thats kind of where my knowledge falls down.

I think once i can get going i can figure it out its just getting the app to open the template.

Their doesnt seem to be much documentation on this and i would think this would come up fairly often.

any help you guys can give would be appreciated

Comment: `Microsoft.Office.Interop` is what you want. What have you tried, what language are you using? Why does that namespace not do what you want?